# ¿Como ejecutar php server desde VS Code?

Tags: php

Estoy buscando gente que me ayude a resolver un problema que estoy teniendo en el VS Code.

Mi profesor pidio que hagamos ejercicios en PHP y dijo que no quiere que usemos **XAMPP** (*yo solo se usar ese*) y dijo que usemos **PHP Server**.

Bueno, instale el `PHP` y la extencion, hice el ejercicio y al momento de ejecutarlo **PHP Not found**

Ya intente lo de entra a `php.validate.executablePath` en config le puse la direccion del archivo y no funciona. Probe distintas maneras y no sé que hacer. ¿Alguno me podría ayudar?

Comment: Hoa Dexuz, sería bueno si pudieras [edit] tu pregunta y agregar: 1) la ruta completa al `php.exe`. 2) La configuración que tenes en el archivo `launch.json`. Imagino que con `PHP Server` te referis al [server built-in](https://www.php.net/manual/en/features.commandline.webserver.php), cierto?